# How can I modify a form during an AjaxRequest?

Tags: wicket

How can I refresh the form inside a Wicket modal dialog during an `AjaxRequest`? I need to write two strings in two text fields, and to change the `List<String>` in a tab by clicking on a button in the form. The models connected to the text fields are defined with `PropertyModel`, while the `List` is connected to a `LoadableDetachableModel`.

Comment: I tried to clean your post up a bit, but if you want a good answer you're going to have to provide more details (probably in the form of code).

Answer (score 0):

Just add these form components and tab panel in the AjaxRequestTarget.
E.g.: target.addComponent(textField1);

Comment: You also have to call `textField1.setOutputMarkupId(true)` when you construct it and add it to the form.